# jsonwebtoken decode returns null

Tags: node.js, jwt

using `jsonwebtoken`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = httpResponse.headers["x-authorization-bearer"].trim();

var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
console.log(token); // eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0.WTMwOGJudHBDTVM3Rm52clBPOGFPUQ.UbXYtb5KppbGYn3AkyOkCg.ljnC5I8q3qThn-NHY6qBqkFhSS9hNiR_pviIFB1zNVmp5Z2wOx0MON2sWRsDF__uSJ-PdI7QaM6djdflbTvKyPWbtKV6g_VDOU-lF6XKMI96BMK41mmBiJSNyDNxE5hqB4X_qWeCYMif8tf583bcKvkrxyuUTsRwvR2Xdo6yl9dyapYGhvKar2TtogOR9-jlFADfPL07ih0YjPYTo2gAWGzrVR6tNuyoRJolYd0ixon5nZ1aP5TdcbPrNcWmGfmuIfWN12BdiEtfrVYDNV7xwmNWfuxke0Uev5VAlIATg_U.1X6R6y9IK3n8NAexswUQKQ
console.log(decoded); // null
```

Comment: Have you obfuscated the JWT in your comment? If you haven't, it doesn't seem to be valid when checking it over at https://jwt.io/.

Comment: @KirkLarkin are you trying to decode with a secret key? because if you go to https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ it does seem to be valid

Comment: I pasted it in at jsonwebtoken.io and it says invalid token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT you've given has 4 `.` characters, but according to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:
>
> Header
> Payload
> Signature
>
> Therefore, a JWT typically looks like the following.
>
> xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

The [`decode`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/decode.js#L5) function in [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) first calls out to a [`decode`](https://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws/blob/master/lib/verify-stream.js#L57) function in [jws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws), which validates against the following [RegEx](https://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws/blob/master/lib/verify-stream.js#L8):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+?\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)?$/
```

Given that your token contains 4 `.` characters, this validation fails and returns `null`, which propagates up to your call site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to instantiate the JSON Web token you wont get the unique token value.In fact you may end up with {} empty inject.

We can make use of the jsonwebtoken in below fashion.
eg. **const token = jwt.sign(payload,SECRET_KEY,{algorithm,expireIn})**